# how do I find the spectrum.......?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let‎ ‎$$H=\ell‎^2=\{(x‎_n)‎_{n=1}^\infty:\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |x|^2<\infty\},$$ so ‎that‎ ‎$S:\ell‎^2‎\rightarrow \ell‎^2‎,$‎
$$ S(x‎_1, x‎_2, \cdots) = (0, x‎_1, x‎_2,\cdots) . $$‎‎

Can you help me how to prove:

> If $‎S ‎\in ‎B(H)=\{ \text{bounded linear operators on } H\}$, and $ ‎‎\| S‎\|= 1 $, then $$‎\sigma(S) = \{ ‎\lambda \in ‎\mathbb{C} : \lambda\leqslant 1\}‎‎$$

Comment: [This](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahlep/111/e04ot5s.pdf) may be useful for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

That $||S||=1$ is easy to see (show that $||Sx||=||x||$ for all $x \in H$.

We get: $\sigma(S)  \subseteq\{ ‎\lambda \in ‎\mathbb{C} : ‎\mid\lambda\mid\leqslant 1\}‎‎$.

Next consider $T:=S^{*}$. We have $T(x‎_{‎1‎}‎, x‎_{‎2‎}‎, \ldots) = (x‎_{‎2‎}‎ , x‎_{‎3}‎,\ldots) $.

Observe that  $ \sigma (T)=  \sigma (S)$

It should be clear, that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Let $ 0<|\mu|<1$ and $x=(1, \mu, \mu^2,...)$

Show that $x \in H$ and that$Tx=\mu x$

We get: $ \{\mu: |\mu|<1\} \subseteq \sigma (T) \subseteq \{\mu: |\mu| \le1\}$

Since $ \sigma (T)$ is closed: $\sigma (T) =\{\mu: |\mu| \le1\}$